# Calling public method within module javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to call a public method from within the module pattern.

I'm using the module pattern because it allows for splitting into various different JS files, to make the code more organised.

However when I call the public method, I get a `TypeError` and also `typeof` remains undefined.

Please help!! Thanks in advance.

#### main.js

```
function MainObject() {
    this.notify = function(msg) { console.log(msg); }
}

var connObj = require("./myextobj");

var mainObj = new MainObject();

connObj.connection.handle = mainObj;

console.log(typeof connObj.connection.connect); // undefined

connObj.connection.connect(); // TypeError: Object has no method 'connect'
```

#### myextobj.js

```
module.exports = {

    connection: function () {

        this.handle = eventhandle;

        this.connect = function() {

            // connect to server
            handle.notify("completed connection....");

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're exporting an object containing `connection: function ()`, which is a constructor function and needs *newing-up*.  Then you can access the `this` properties attached to that particular instance:

```
var connection = require("./myextobj").connection; // reference the constructor function

var conn = new connection(); // new-up connection

console.log(typeof conn.connect); // -> function
```

**Edit:**

If the only thing exported by `myextobj.js` is the constructor function, there's no need to wrap it up in a literal object.  I.e. you could do:

```
module.exports = function Connection() {    
    this.handle = eventhandle;
    this.connect = function() {
        handle.notify("completed connection....");
    }
}
```

then use like so:

```
var Connection = require("./myextobj");
```

Note: `.connection` is no longer appended to the end to reference the function.

Comment: nb: by convention "constructor functions" start with a capital letter.

Comment: Yep, but I didn't want to deviate too far from the original code, to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a shot.

```
 var module = {};
module.exports = {

    connection: function () {

        return {
            handle: eventhandle,

            connect: function () {

                // connect to server
                handle.notify("completed connection....");

            }
        }
    }()
}

module.exports.connection.connect()
```

Comment: Not sure who -1 this one but this is the a good answer. Imme2209 asked for a module pattern. Have you guys forgotten what a module pattern is.

Comment: That wasn't my DV (I got one too), but I can see why you did.  In node, `require` returns the value of `module.exports` for the module being _required_. Simply referencing `module.exports.connection` in the same context is not demonstrative of the module pattern.